# i was watching Reducible's video about recursion and saw this code and i cant understand how it works could someone please explain?

Tags: python, recursion

```
# function counts number of ways you can
# partition n objects 
# using parts up to m (assume m>=0)
n=int(input('enter n '))
m=int(input('enter m '))
def count(n, m):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    elif m==0 or n<0:
        return 0
    else:
        return count(n-m , m)+count(n , m-1)
print(count(n,m))
```

I don't understand the inputs and outputs of every function, I want to learn this and I am getting discouraged I hope someone could help I especially don't understand how it returns one value from this function, not two.
(this is my first post I don't know if it's the correct format).

Comment: @Barmar hi thank you for the reply "count" is a name i gave the function, when it calls the function doesnt it have an n value and an m value? doesnt it add the n+n and m+m ? i am a complete beginner, sorry if this is wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand the inputs and outputs of every function

The inputs are the total number of objects `n`, and the maximum size of the partitions that it can be split into `m`.

The output is the count of the number of possible partitions fitting that criteria.

For instance, if `n == 3` and `m == 2`, the possible partitions are 3 partitions with 1 item each, or 2 partitions with 2 and 1 items. So the output is 2.

> I especially don't understand how it returns one value from this function, not two

The base cases clearly each return just a single value. One of them returns `1`, the other returns `0`.

If it doesn't return immediately from one of the base cases, it calls itself recursively twice, with smaller values of one of the parameters. So each recursive call gets closer to one of the base cases. When these return, it adds the results together, so it's only returning one value, not both values.

Comment: thank you so much! I spent hours on this and you just made it very simple thank you!